# Can I pass a custom text argument to the command palette in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-keybinding

I would like to setup a custom key binding in vscode that passes `@:` as an argument (or prefix) to the Command Palette, through the `workbench.action.quickOpen` command. The `@:` prefix is meant to show all symbols by category. I essentially want a single key binding that performs the following two steps:

1. Command + P (to open the command palette)
2. @: (to show and then search symbols sorted by category)

I have tried the following in my `keybindings.json`, but it only opens the Command Palette without passing the `@:` text as an argument or prefix:

```
    {
      "key": "ctrl+l",
      "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
      "args": { "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen", "text": "@:"},
    }
```

Comment: related command: `Go To Symbol in Editor` (`workbench.action.gotoSymbol`) (opens with `@`, but not `@:`) but does that command solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the `gotoSymbol` command does not sort by category and there does not seem to be a `workbench.action` to mimic the `@:` prefix, so I'm looking for a way to pass it in as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this keybinding:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen",
    "args": "@:"   
},
```

The argument is quite simple, you would expect something like:

```json
"args": {
   "text": "@:"    // ERROR
}
```

but the correct form is just

```json
"args": "@:"      // GOOD
```

probably a historical artifact of being an early command before the arguments got more standardized.

And you don't need `multiCommand`, it isn't helpful here.